# PHP's session_start causes the page to not be found

Tags: php, session, xampp

I have a basic "signup" page, and in it, I want to load session variables so part of the form can be repopulated. The problem is, if I call `session_start`, it causes my page to not be found:

[image: Page Not Found]

It doesn't even load enough for me to check for any errors.

I know it's because of `session_start` since commenting out the call to it causes my page to load.

This is output into my Apache log:

```
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:21.325743 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5012:tid 544] AH00428: Parent: child process 14060 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:21.964852 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 544] AH01909: 127.0.0.1:8080:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.011733 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5012:tid 544] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.011733 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5012:tid 544] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.011733 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5012:tid 544] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.011733 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5012:tid 544] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12716
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.666227 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12716:tid 552] AH01909: 127.0.0.1:8080:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.828422 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12716:tid 552] AH01909: 127.0.0.1:8080:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 29 17:45:22.881476 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12716:tid 552] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads
```

And the server doesn't have the request in it's log.

The page code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['mismatch'])) {
        define('MISMATCH_ERROR', true);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['missing'])) {
        define('MISSING_ERROR', true);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['exists'])) {
        define('EXISTS_ERROR', true);
    }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Signup Page</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 150%;
        }

        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10em;
        }

        form {
            border: 2px groove darkgreen;

            <?php 
                if (defined('MISSING_ERROR')) {
                    echo "background-color: red;";
                }
            ?>
        }

        <?php
            if (defined('MISMATCH_ERROR')) {
                echo "
                    input[type='password'] {
                        background-color: red;
                    }
                ";
            }
        ?>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="handleSignup.php">
        <label for="usernameInput">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />

        <br />

        <label for="passwordInput">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>

        <br />

        <label for="passwordReInput">Retype Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwordRe" />

        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        <?php
            if (defined('EXISTS_ERROR')) {
                echo "Username already exists.";
            }
        ?>


    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And I checked `phpinfo()`, and sessions are enabled.

I'm using XAMPP 3.2.2

Comment: Try session_start(); echo 'hello earth'; on its own page to exclude any other coding errors.

Comment: @Progrock Good idea. Confirmed not working on stripped down test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being `session.use_cookies` in `php.ini`. It was off by default, despite it recommending it to be enabled, so I toggled it, and it works now.

Don't forgot to restart the server after making the changes.

## Update:

For some reason after installing Netbeans, the problem started again. I needed to also enable `session.always_use_cookies` for it to work again.

Comment: It should be noted however that I wasn't able to check whether or not the sessions actually worked (my break ended), this change only allowed the page to load. I'll test to make sure it's actually working on my next break.

Answer (score 1):

how do you store sessions ? if in file check the session path and check if its writable.

You also check `session.gc_*` settings (garbage collector)

Comment: I'm using file storage. I'll check the file writability.

Comment: The file path is correct and writable. I'm not sure what I'm looking for in the session gc settings. It's set to gc every 24 minutes, but that shouldn't be a problem. If I can get logged in on my laptop here, I'll post my gc settings above.